# char array comparison

Tags: string

I'm having some issues dealing with strings in a small Arduino app.
I wonder why **this code works**:

```
mqtt.setServer("192.168.1.42", port);
```

and this code doesn't:

```
IPAddress ip = MDNS.queryHost(...);
mqtt.setServer(ip.toString().c_str(), port);
```

Even when `strcmp` returns 0 when I compare both:

```
strcmp(ip.toString().c_str(), "192.168.1.42"); // output = 0 => equality
```

I've also tried other alternatives, such as creating a `char` array, with no luck:

```
String ipstr = ip.toString();
char ipchar[ipstr.length() + 1];
ipstr.toCharArray(ipchar, ipstr.length() + 1);

mqtt.setServer(ipchar, port);
```

All alternatives compile, but the mqtt connection is never established later on. I must be missing something obvious because it works when I hardcode the "192.168.1.42" string.

Comment: What does the `mqtt.setServer` do? Does it store a pointer reference or does it copy the input string to its own buffers? If you use a constant "192.168.1.42" then that string will be static. WHen you use `ip.toString().c_str()`, when the `ip` object is deallocated but `.setServer()` still has a reference to that `char*`, it's become invalid. Where is the library you're using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PubSubClient::setServer(const char * domain, uint16_t port)` just saves the pointer, it doesn't copy the string (probably because it expects a static string literal).
([Source](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/f029640ee6365c58ebfe66ebf6bf1733d322f2ec/src/PubSubClient.cpp#L566))
In your case, when `ip` goes out of scope, the pointer is no longer valid, so it won't work.

Just use the `PubSubClient::setServer(IPAddress ip, uint16_t port)` function instead.
([Source](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/f029640ee6365c58ebfe66ebf6bf1733d322f2ec/src/PubSubClient.h#L118))

Always read the [API documentation](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api.html#setserver), most libraries have one, even though it can be hard to find. The ReadMe and GitHub Wiki pages are a good place to start.
If that's insufficient (not uncommon for open source projects), read the [header files](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/f029640ee6365c58ebfe66ebf6bf1733d322f2ec/src/PubSubClient.h), which list all functions of the library.
If you still have doubts about what a function does, refer to the actual [implementation files](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/f029640ee6365c58ebfe66ebf6bf1733d322f2ec/src/PubSubClient.cpp).